# How to auto expand textarea as we write

Tags: javascript, css, textarea, expand

How can I auto expand my text area as I write?

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function clearContents(element) {
                  element.value = '';
                }
                function updateContents(element) {
                  element.value = "What's on your mind?";
                }
            </script>
            <h1>New status</h1>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" name="new_message">
                <textarea id="message" onFocus="clearContents(this);" onKeyPress="catchEnter(this);">What's on your mind?</textarea>
                <input type="button" value="Post"> 
            </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been using the [elastic textbox from Unwrongest](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/) and it's a fantastic plugin.

Just include the plugin, and then call the plugin with just this:

```
$('#TextAreaId').elastic();
```

that's it.

Check out a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/janjarfalk/r3Ekw/

---

how to achieve this in 3 steps:

**step 1**: Add this to your `<head>` in your html:

```
http://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.elastic.source.js
```

**step 2**: Add this to your html file, just before `</body>` tag:

```
$('textarea').elastic();
```

**step 3**: use this step ONLY if it doesn't work after step 2. Add the next line above your code from step 1:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You are done. If you already have jQuery, skip step 3.

Comment: you will need JQuery for this though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea onkeyup="textarea(this);"></textarea>

<script>
function textarea(box){
box.style.height = box.scrollHeight+'px';
}
</script>
```

Then Bam!!! you have a growing textarea. You may have to account for borders and padding. include those in the function.

Comment: This solution only works when your text box doesn't need to contract.